# Add Ajax Add To Cart Button to Front Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to add ajax to add to cart button on front page.

The setup is using Divi. Divi's woo product module does not display Add-to-cart button. I use the below to display add-to-cart button on front page. That works but the only issue is the Ajax is not working on front page. I've enabled "Enable AJAX add to basket buttons on archives" from Woocommerce settings.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'work_only_on_front_page', 10);
   function work_only_on_front_page(){
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
 add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10);
   }
   }
```

Below works well on other pages other than the front page.

```
(function ($) {

    $(document).on('click', '.single_add_to_cart_button', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $thisbutton = $(this),
                $form = $thisbutton.closest('form.cart'),
                id = $thisbutton.val(),
                product_qty = $form.find('input[name=quantity]').val() || 1,
                product_id = $form.find('input[name=product_id]').val() || id,
                variation_id = $form.find('input[name=variation_id]').val() || 0;

        var data = {
            action: 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart',
            product_id: product_id,
            product_sku: '',
            quantity: product_qty,
            variation_id: variation_id,
        };

        $(document.body).trigger('adding_to_cart', [$thisbutton, data]);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function (response) {
                $thisbutton.removeClass('added').addClass('loading');
            },
            complete: function (response) {
                $thisbutton.addClass('added').removeClass('loading');
            },
            success: function (response) {

                if (response.error && response.product_url) {
                    window.location = response.product_url;
                    return;
                } else {
                    $(document.body).trigger('added_to_cart', [response.fragments, response.cart_hash, $thisbutton]);
                }
            },
        });

        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```
function woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart_js() {
    if (is_product() || is_product_category() || is_shop() || is_front_page()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('woocommerce-ajax-add-to-cart', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/ajax-add-to-cart.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart_js', 99);
add_action('wp_ajax_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart');
        
function woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart() {

            $product_id = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint($_POST['product_id']));
            $quantity = empty($_POST['quantity']) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount($_POST['quantity']);
            $variation_id = absint($_POST['variation_id']);
            $passed_validation = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity);
            $product_status = get_post_status($product_id);

          if ($passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id) && 'publish' === $product_status) {

                do_action('woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id);

                if ('yes' === get_option('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add')) {
                    wc_add_to_cart_message(array($product_id => $quantity), true);
                }

                WC_AJAX :: get_refreshed_fragments();
            } else {

                $data = array(
                    'error' => true,
                    'product_url' => apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink($product_id), $product_id));

                echo wp_send_json($data);
            }

            wp_die();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Another thing to check is to ensure that the function woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart_js() is being called and the script is being enqueued on the front page.
- You can check the browser's console to see if there are any errors related to the Javascript code not being loaded.

Comment: Thanks. yes, they are enqueued correctly and loaded on the front page.

Comment: Guess I found the cause of ajax not working on front page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75216729/is-this-hook-the-only-hook-for-add-to-cart-button